# Implementing Live Stream box and requiring app authorization

Tags: facebook, stream, live, facebook-oauth, facebook-login

I've got the Live Stream box plugin working on my site using the code output from the developer documentation. What I want to do is when a user clicks login it asks for authorisation to use the app with the permissions e.g. email address, that I've requested in the auth part of the app. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

use the scope parameter

see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Comment: Could you expand. This is the code I have: <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APP_ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script> <div class="fb-live-stream" data-event-app-id="xxxxxxx" data-width="400" data-height="500" data-always-post-to-friends="false"></div>

Comment: i did not understand which api you are using, add the scope parameter in the url //connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APP_ID&scope=email

Comment: i think you cannot ask for extended permission like email etc here

Comment: use the scope parameter in your javascript SDk see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/